# Converting an object with multiple arrays to a multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, json

I have this format:

```
Data = {
    "count": [ 62, 58, 10, 6 ],
    "categoires": [ "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" ]
}
```

I need to get get data in to the following format:

```
data = [
    [ "a1", 62 ],
    [ "a2", 58 ],
    [ "a3", 10 ],
    [ "a4", 6 ]
]
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and get the elements from both arrays at the current index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `while` loop

```js
var data = {
     "count": [62, 58, 10, 6],
     "categoires": ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
   }

   var res = [], // array to push values to
     i = 0, // begin at index `0`
     len = data["categoires"].length; // max length

   while (i < len) {
     res.push([data["categoires"][i], data["count"][i]]); // push data tob `res`
     ++i; // increment index
   }

console.log(res);

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)
```

```css
body {
  white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: How can i print value?

Comment: _"How can i print value?"_ `res` contains values . See updated post; try `console.log(res)`

Comment: _"yes i did not geting value "_  ? Tried stacksnippets ? Added `JSON.stringify(res)` to print values to `document.body`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop using `for` and `length` properties:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Data.count.length; i++)
    data[i] = [ Data.categoires[i], Data.count[i] ];
```